# Redux - Reset state of subtree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

What is the proper way to reset the subtree of a redux store?  I'm not interested in resetting the entire redux store, but just the reducer subtree portion of it.

Here is an example snippet:

```
//initial state
const initialState = {
    isFetching: false,
    error: '',
    page: 0
}

//reducer for suggestions store
export default function suggestions (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCHING_SUGGESTIONS : {
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: true
            }
        }
        case FETCHING_SUGGESTIONS_SUCCESS : {
            return {
                ...state,
                [action.suggestion.suggestionId] : action.suggestion
            }
        }
        case FETCHING_SUGGESTIONS_ERROR : {
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: false,
                error: "Error in fetching suggestions"
            }
        }
        case CHANGE_PAGE : {
            return {
                ...state,
                page: action.page
            }
        }
        case ADD_SUGGESTION : {
            return {
                ...state,
                [action.suggestion.suggestionId]: action.suggestion
            }
        }
        case CLEAR_SUGGESTIONS : {
            return {
                initialState
            }
        }
        default : 
            return state
    }
}
```

I would think this would work, however whenever the CLEAR_SUGGESTIONS action is dispatched, I suddenly get undefined props in some of my components and the following error:
    warning.js:36 Warning: performUpdateIfNecessary: Unexpected batch number (current 161, pending 157)

I'm not 100% confident I'm doing this correctly.  Can someone confirm if the issue is with my reducer, or somewhere along my components lifecycle methods?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accidentally nesting initialState under a key called 'initialState. You just want:

```
case CLEAR_SUGGESTIONS : {
  return initialState
}
```

There's no need to copy initialState, since store state is immutable.

Comment: I see, you were right.  I had tested this previously as well.  I'm starting to believe there is an issue with my components not updating properly when this redux state subtree is reset.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The object you create will look like this:

```
{
  initialState: {
    isFetching: false,
    error: '',
    page: 0
  }
}
```

What you want is this:

```
case CLEAR_SUGGESTIONS : {
  return {
    ...initialState
  }
}
```

Comment: The results are the same.  If this is the correct way to handle resetting the subtree state, then perhaps something else is wrong with my components...  Thanks